# How do I format SQL Server 2008 Date in M/DD/YYYY h:mm am Format?

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

How to you display a date in the following format with lower case am or pm? MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a

I've searched in Stack Overflow, but no one seems to ask for this exact format. I am close, but I can't get the seconds to hide:

```
declare @X datetime
set @X = '2012-01-25 05:24:05 pm' --this needs to show as 01/25/2012 5:24 pm

select LOWER(CONVERT(varchar(10), @X, 101) + ' ' + 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(26), @X, 109), 13, 8) + ' ' + 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(26), @X, 109), 25, 2))
```

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp  _select DATE_FORMAT(@X,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')_

Comment: @PaulF Sorry, tagged the question wrong. SQL Server instead of MySQL.

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov - SQL Server 2008-R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @X datetime
set @X = '2012-01-25 05:24:05 pm' --this needs to show as 01/25/2012 5:24 pm

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @X, 101) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @X, 100),CHARINDEX (' ',REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @X, 100))))
```

Result:

```
01/25/2012  5:24PM
```

Remark: There is missing space between AM/PM and minutes. If it is improtant use this:

```
declare @X datetime
declare @stringX varchar(100)
set @X = '2012-01-25 05:24:05 pm' --this needs to show as 01/25/2012 5:24 pm

SELECT @stringX = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @X, 101) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @X, 100),CHARINDEX (' ',REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @X, 100))))

SELECT LEFT (@stringX, LEN(@stringX)-2) + ' ' + LOWER(RIGHT(@stringX, 2))
```

Result:

```
01/25/2012 5:24 pm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @d datetime, @t time
SET @d = GETDATE()
SET @t = CAST(@d AS time)

SELECT 
    (
        CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @d, 101) +
        ' ' +
        SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(15), @t, 100), 1, CHARINDEX('M', CONVERT(nvarchar(15), @t, 100), 1) - 2) +
        ' ' +
        SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(15), @t, 100), CHARINDEX('M', CONVERT(nvarchar(15), @t, 100), 1) - 1, 2)
    )
```

Comment: Works great - the only thing I'd say is to also add the lower function to your answer on there so am/pm is lowercase. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try the MySQL manual page on the date formatting :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Sorry - I updated the question. I'm using SQL Server 2008-R2 instead of MySQL.